# $scope.$watch with a complex variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to $scope.$watch a variable like this:

```
$scope.data.localization[$scope.locale].properties[0].value
```

**$scope.data.localization[$scope.locale].properties** is an array of objects where each object has a code and a value, I use these couples to create dynamic forms:

```
<input type="text" ng-repeat="property in $scope.data.localization[$scope.locale].properties" ng-model="property.value" />
```

Now, some textbox must be visible only if another textbox has a value, so basically I wanted to $scope.$watch one of those values but it doesn't work, the callback of the $watch is never fired:

```
$scope.$watch("data.localization." + $scope.locale +".properties[0].value", function () {
   //show/hide another texbox if I have a value
});
```

Any idea how to implement that?

EDIT: I tried

```
$scope.$watch("data.localization", function () {
   //show/hide another texbox if I have a value
});
```

and it fires the callback, so it looks like the problem is the dynamic property **$scope.locale** but I don't know how to avoid that.

The problem is that if I watch the whole array, I don't know what value changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myWatcher = "data.localization." + $scope.locale +".properties[0].value";    
$scope.$watch(myWatcher, function () {
   //show/hide another texbox if I have a value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function in a watch to return the value to watch.  Try:

```
$scope.$watch(function () { return $scope.data.localization[$scope.locale].properties[0].value; } , function () {
   //show/hide another texbox if I have a value
});
```

Comment: Well, it works, the problem is that if I put that line inside a for loop it always keep the last property. Actually the real code is $scope.data.localization[$scope.locale].properties[idx].value; Where idx is the index of the property I need to watch